# Is it possible to have a db model and an ndb model in the same entity group?

Tags: google-app-engine, app-engine-ndb

We have a db model, `Vote` that we've been using for a while and recently added an ndb model, `Score` which represents the cumulative score of an entity, based on its votes. Currently `Score` is the parent of its votes because we want them all to be in the same entity group (so they can be updated in the same transaction). I've been trying to get a transaction to work that would update both `Vote` and `Score` but it consistently fails. Here's some sample code:

```
    def transaction():
        score = self.key_score.get()
        vote = db.get(self.key_vote)

        # do stuff

        score.put()
        vote.put()
    db.run_in_transaction(transaction)
```

From what I can tell (dev server only) this always retries four times:

```
WARNING:root:Transaction collision. Retrying...
WARNING:root:Transaction collision. Retrying...
WARNING:root:Transaction collision. Retrying...
WARNING:root:Transaction collision. Retrying...
ERROR
```

Then I get "TransactionFailedError: The transaction could not be committed. Please try again.".

I've tried a few things to fix this:

1. Change the order of the gets and the puts - I thought maybe there was an entity group locking problem that I don't understand but switching the order of the gets or the puts didn't change the behavior.
2. Asynchronous puts. This is actually what I started with - the only way I know of to concurrently put a db and an ndb model (I think this is essentially what putting multiple keys does behind the scenes). Same result.

   ```
   score_future = score.put_async()
   vote_future = db.put_async(vote)
   score_future.get_result()
   vote_future.get_result()
   ```
3. replace `db.run_in_transaction` with `ndb.transaction`. This throws "AttributeError: 'Key' object has no attribute 'reference'" on the `db.get`. I'm not sure what's going on here - looks like some behind the scenes code is getting `db.Key` where it expects `ndb.Key`.

Interestingly, I can run the same code as above if I remove the `parent` relationship, meaning the entities are not in the same entity group.

So, is it possible to have both db and ndb models in the same entity group? Maybe there's an easy way to get a db model as ndb or vice-versa?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

All entities look the same to the datastore, regardless of whether they're created with DB or NDB. The problem here is that you're trying to mix the two in an API call; db doesn't know what to do when passed an ndb model instance.

You need to create an NDB model that's identical to your db model for Vote - or better yet, migrate Vote to an NDB model - and use that in any code where you need a transaction for both entity types.